# copy text in square brackets in filemaker pro

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to do  script in Filemaker Pro to copy any text in square brackets in a field.

The text will vary in length and position, can't seem to get anything to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please include the script as well as demonstration of the issue you're encountering. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have been using a variable and the scrip -  Middle ( 
Sales::Temp_G
 ; 
Position ( Sales::Temp_G ; "[" ; 0 ; 1 ) +1
 ; 
Position ( Sales::Temp_G ; "]" ; 0 ; 1 ) -1 
 )

Comment: It's best if you edit your question, rather than adding comments. Use suitable formatting (check out [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and elaborate the detail so that the whole question reads well from start to end. Don't be afraid of providing extra detail in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the text inside the first pair of square brackets by using the following calculation =

```
Let ( [
start = Position ( YourField ; "[" ; 1 ; 1 ) + 1 ;
end = Position ( YourField ; "]" ; 1 ; 1 ) 
] ;
Middle ( YourField ; start ; end - start )
)
```

Note that this assumes your field contains at least one pair of square brackets.

Comment: Hi,Thanks, that worked great, helped me notice too that I had forgotten I had to calculate the length.  Don't do much scripting but this sort of thing really makes it so much easier.